# How to filter date column using VBA with 2 criteria?

Tags: vba, date, filter

I have a column in a table that contains blanks and dates. How do I code in VBA the option to exclude blanks and dates in the future?

Answer (score 1):

This should filter out the blanks and future dates.

Note that it will only filter these out of the columns that you specify as `Field` (based on column number), so if you want to hide all blanks instead of just one column's blanks, you can repeat that line and adjust as necessary (or use a loop).

```
Sub FilterBlankAndDates()

    With sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<=" & Date
    End With

End Sub
```